# Is there any Data sharing mechanism in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is there any data sharing mechanism exists in the linux kernel? Is there any need also for that? Is there anything like IPC inside kernel?

Comment: All kernel memory pages are available in any kernel code (there is no division like between user-space processes pages). So you basically can declare some global variable in one kernel file and use it from outside (from another kernel file). Or you are asking about shared memory between kernel and user-space?

Comment: data sharing between what and what?

Comment: @Sam: yes my question is inside the kernel only. Not related to user space. In the kernel, we can create kthreads. If two kthreads has to share the data or they have to share data from any other kernel module. What is the mechanism. And also you've given me one more question how it happens between kernel space and user space.. Is that happens through mmap?

Comment: @SandeepTayal In that case you just need to provide data (variable) from one file to other, e.g. making this variable global, or passing it via some function, as param. Then you just need to take care about multi-threading, which means you need to lock this variable in each thread, using some locking mechanism like mutex, spinlock, semaphores, RCU, atomic operations etc. I recommend you to read "Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition" and "Linux Kernel Development, 3rd edition" for details. There is no need to repeat those books here. Bottom line -- you can access any kernel page anywhere in kernel

Comment: From my experience shared memory is the best way to implement IPC in Linux Kernel.

Answer (score -1):

There lots of them: pipes, unix sockets, sysv message queues, posix message queues, shared memory, etc...

shared memory is the fastest. pipes work only in one direction, but unix sockets in both. unix sockets work like normal ip sockets, they use udp or tcp. with message queues, you write to a queue and retrieve data later, or in an other process.

Comment: OP asks about kernel, where is no need to use userspace facilities (its just a burdain)

Comment: you are speaking when you are hacking the linux kernel? when so, you can use skb i think (sockets in kernel space). but better use shared memory is much faster and sync access to it with spin loops.